# Git: Undo revert on local file in Aptana Studio

Tags: git, aptana, local, undo, revert

I have accidentally clicked on "Revert" option over the wrong file in Aptana Studio losing every single change I made on that file. The thing here is that I DO need that file because I can't remember every single change I made...

So in order to get you out of a possible confusion, this is the order of the events:

1. Pull every single content in the Branch.
2. Make vast changes on a
   file.
3. I wanted to Stash and Commit this file, but instead I Revert
   it losing everything.
4. I want to kill myself. :'(

Any solution guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No solution with git and probably no solution at all, because the revert overwrote the changes you made. So a tool to recover deleted files most likely won't work here. BTW: Even killing yourself will not bring it back, so that isn't a solution, either :-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have to deal with my mistake... Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

No solution with Git but Aptana is based on Eclipse and Eclipse maintains a local history of changes to files.

You should be able to right click on your file then select the menu "Compare With" (or "Replace With") and then "Local history". In the history tab which appears on the bottom you can select the concrete history version.

When you click on a folder you should be able to restore a deleted file with the same method.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Tried your method but there was no trace of that old copy... Nevermind I am already working on the code again. Thanks for your answer! ^^